# What is the difference between `tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator` and `tf.train.WorkerSessionCreator`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The arg `is_chief` will decide different type of session creator to use in the `MonitoredTrainingSession`. When `is_chief=True`, it will use `tf.train.ChiefSessionCreator` otherwise to use the `tf.train.WorkerSessionCreator`.

So I want to know the difference between these two session creators.

Here are the [official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/python/train#Distributed_execution), but there is no more information.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs of [MonitoredSession](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py#L303)

> is_chief: If `True`, it will take care of initialization and recovery the
>         underlying TensorFlow session. If `False`, it will wait on a chief to
>         initialize or recover the TensorFlow session.

ChiefSessionCreator (see True) is the session creator, which takes the lead and prepares the environment including the var-initializer. The WorkerSessionCreator (see False) just joins the work pool and assumes everything is set up.